# Node gathering on 2 other guest servers in guild wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

From what I read that besides my home server I can gather nodes (orichalcum, ancient wood) on 2 other guest servers. After I gathered on IOJ (home server) and tried guesting on SBI/JQ, I cant seem to find any nodes. This was in cursed shores/malchor leap.

So is there a way to find out which other 2 server, will have nodes spawn that I can gather?

Comment: As I understand it nodes are not always in the same place.

Comment: I've been having the same problems as well harvesting on blackgate and dragonbrand and it seems like there is actually a map limit and maybe certain nodes have something like a specific identifier and regardless of map location it is still nodeA or nodeB. Cause I swear harvesting in a guest server and then switching is making nodes in the other server unharvestable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, seems like there's a website for everything GW2-related these days :-)

Simply go to http://gw2ores.celsodantas.com/ and choose your server(s).

Note that the limitation of 2 servers is due to not being able to guest on more than two (non-home) servers at a time, not due to gathering limitations. You can even use the above site to choose which servers you'd like to guest to based on how many known nodes there are. It lists only top-level nodes (orichalcum/ancient wood/omnomberries, i.e. not mithril etc.), and of course if you find nodes that aren't already shown, you can add them simply by right-clicking and choosing the type of node. Obviously this is open to a bit of abuse but generally I've found it to be very accurate. You can also help out by confirming existing nodes via the right-click menu.

Nodes spawn each time a server restarts, so any time you need to download a new game update, the information becomes outdated and nodes may be at completely different locations on different servers (though there is a finite list of possible spawn locations).

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderful answer, that website is very accurate too. I want to upvote your answer but I need like 15rep before I can do that :(

Comment: @thon: No problems about the vote, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I cant find many nodes on the other servers as well. This is while looking on current, updated maps of their locations. Someone told me that even on guest servers you cannot mine the same node in the same location as a server you have already mined it on. However, I am looking at locations that I am positive I have NOT mined, and STILL I cannot find the nodes (at least not on the mini map). Specifically, im looking for ancient wood.

Actually, to be more clear, I *can* find the actual nodes. However, they are not shown on the minimap, and when I find them they are not mineable/chopable. They are not shown as already mined or chopped, either. They are just there, unable to be interacted with.

It almost seems like once you find all of a particular node on a particular map on a particular server, all of those specific nodes are not available to you on that specific map on other servers.

I imagine this is something new?